# Help with UIPageControl and UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I need help with `UIPageControl`. In my application I've made an `UISCrollView`

> Width: 640
>
> Height: 300
>
> Paging enabled
>
> Horizontal Scroll Only

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [ScrollView setContentSize:CGRectMake (640, 300)];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I want `UIPageControl` to change the number of the page when the users scroll the view and surpass 320 pix, like in the iPhone Springboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tutorial,

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.